# Simple circuit for a single 10 ms pulse when closing a contact switch

Tags: bjt, pulse

I have a simple circuit (see image below) that creates a single 10 ms pulse when closing a contact switch (SPST) but I also need that after generating a pulse the circuit will wait some time (500 ms for example) until being able to generate a new pulse. The pulse generation works fine but I'm having trouble implementing the wait time, my circuit will generate a pulse each time the contact is closed. Any clues on how to do this please?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were going to design such a circuit, I would borrow techniques from the traditional transistor multivibrator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f438wf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you run the simulation, you'll see that it produces one output pulse for every six input pulses. The lockout period is just over 500 ms.

Adjust C1 and R4 to control the output pulse width.

Adjust C2 and R6 to control the lockout period.

R2 and D2 make sure that the output pulse is the full width even if the switch closure is shorter.

D3 and D4 are required because the supply voltage is so high relative to the reverse BE breakdown voltage of the transistors. If the circuit could be run on, say 5V, they could be eliminated.

---

Note that my original circuit shown above (now slightly modified to save a part) will "auto repeat" at about a 2 Hz rate if the switch is held down. A slight additional modification (C3, R7, R8, below) eliminates this behavior, giving one pulse per switch operation, regardless of how long it is held.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbz9Bm.png)</sup>

Comment: Your circuit looks promising, going to try it. Can I replace the 2N3904 by the ZXTD09N50DE6 (two NPN), they look identical except for the turn on turn off times, the ZXTD09N50DE6 is much slower. Does this circuit needs a fast transistor?

Comment: A little bit complicated but interesting...

Comment: Any reasonably generic NPN transistor should work fine. I see no issues in the ZXTD09N50DE6 datasheet.

Comment: Going for this solution, it works well with the rest of the circuit I already have.

Comment: Just a side question, when you use several ZXTD09N50DE6 (dual NPN) but you have an odd number of transistors, do you need to connect any of the pins of the ZXTD09N50DE6 second transistor that is not used? Or just leave them floating? Or use a single transistor instead?

Comment: Floating is fine.

Comment: Didn't notice your new circuit and got mixed up with your edit, but I think I got it now, you modified the first circuit above, and you added a new circuit with filtering at the SW so it doesn't re-trigger. Ok, going to check all this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxuffy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The simpliest way is to ad an RC delay circuit. The pulse will reach the transistor base immediately after crossing C1. In the meantime, C3 is being filled. And then will continue to supply C1 after SW1 is turned off.

For better control of delay and pulse time, and to get a sharper signal, add a schmitt trigger between D1 and the transistor. Without a shmitt trigger.

I modified values of C1 and R3 to what seemed more appropriate to me. But it's up to your discretion.
Values for R3, R4 and C3 (in my schematic) are not defined precisely for your delay time, so I wrote 10K, 100 ohms and 10uF.

This is the version with schmitt triggers. D2 prevent the schnitt trigger to sink the incoming signal when its output is low. D1 prevents reverse current caused by the discharge of C1. R6,7,8 ensure that things goes back to logic low after a delay.
All values can be modified.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWbs9F.png)</sup>

Comment: I don't see how this provides a 500-ms "lockout" function. As soon as C3 discharges even a little bit, there will be a transient that can pass through C1. You do realize that R3 and R4 are simply in parallel with each other, right?

Comment: Q1 will NOT function properly without a bias resistor. As drawn it could "leak" CE current of a few microamps to milliamps depending on ambient temperature.

Comment: Schematic updated. I still recommend using a schmitt trigger between D1 and Q1. The schematic shows the most simplified solution. And maybe using a MOSFET instead of a NPN transistor. But this is up to you.

Comment: I tried this type of solution and it doesn't work well, as soon as the C3 capacitor discharges a little then the SW pulse will go through C1, the disabled time is too small and hard to tune. @DaveTweed solution works better.

Comment: @PedroNF If C3 discharge too fast, increase impedence of R1. C1 will also discharge more slowly, which is the goal. As long as C1 rtemains charged, the pulse doesn't go through but it takes litte to let pass it again. To tune the delay time and the pulse time with more accuracy, add a schmitt trigger after D1 and ideally, after R4 too. With a schmitt trigger you can control delays much better than without. Since you asked for a "simple" circuit I didn't include it in my schematic. ;)

Comment: See version with schmitt trigger in my edited answer. Should be much more predictable.

Comment: What kind of Schmitt trigger works at 24V?

Comment: @Dave Tweed Good question. That the circuit is on 24V makes it much more complicated, I admit. You have much more possibilities when the logic circuit is supplied or regulated with 5V and then activates 24V lines.